# Image Scraper pushing all attachments from single message to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, github, discord.js

I've been using this script here https://github.com/17teen/Discord-Image-Scraper but stumbled on an issue where it scrapes from a single message that contains say 5 attachments and pulls them to the JSON array as a whole instead of separating them into individual links as if it was an image per message.

I've tried using `.replace(',','')` and `.join(',')` in both `post.js` and the `scraper.js`
and still face this issue.

```json
[
"https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/831804312538841088/893067795154231337/IMG_20210930_113200.jpg,https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/831804312538841088/893067795322011668/IMG_20210930_113039.jpg,https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/831804312538841088/893067795535900702/IMG_20210930_112940.jpg,https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/831804312538841088/893067795741437952/IMG_20210930_113006.jpg","EXTRA","EXTRA"
]
```

Comment: Try doing `thatArray[0].split(",")`

Comment: Thanks for that solution @MrMythical, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@MrMythical](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15781079/mrmythical) for the fix solution to the problem.

For anyone using this code, the fix is below:

The original code was

```js
webhookCli.send(link.split(",")).then((msg) => { 
     spinner.succeed(greenBright(`[${index}] Link Posted: ${yellowBright(msg.content)}`))
}).catch((err) => { 
   spinner.fail(red(`[${index}] Link failed to post | ${err}`)) 
})
```

**IMPROVED CODE**
Added solution to `link`

```js
// Settings
const { webHook_id, webHook_token } = require("./settings.json");
const { greenBright, red, grey, yellowBright } = require("chalk");
const ora = require("ora");
const readline = require("readline").createInterface({ input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout });

// Modules
const { WebhookClient } = require("discord.js");

// Webhook
const webhookCli = new WebhookClient(webHook_id, webHook_token);

readline.question(grey("[?] Do you wish to post these links? (Y/N) "), (answr) => {
    if (answr === "Y" || answr === "y" || answr === "Yes" || answr === "yes" || answr === "YES") return Post()
    if (answr === "N" || answr === "n" || answr === "No" || answr === "no" || answr === "NO") return process.exit(1);
});

/**
 * Posts links to a specifed channel
 */
function Post() {
    const spinner = ora("Preparing to post").start();
    const fetchLinks = require("./links.json")
    fetchLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        webhookCli.send(link.split(",")).then((msg) => { spinner.succeed(greenBright(`[${index}] Link Posted: ${yellowBright(msg.content)}`)) }).catch((err) => { spinner.fail(red(`[${index}] Link failed to post | ${err}`)) })
    });
}
```